# Unable to move file: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-redemption

Scenario: I've written an application to open a list of .msg files (which have been dumped to the file system), grab some information from them (subject, To CC) and then move them.

Problem: However, when it comes to moving the file I get the following error:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by
> another process.

Running Handle against the file only shows the tool I've written and no other handles.

I assume, therefore, that I'm not properly releasing the files when I've finished using them as Redemption MessageItem objects.

But I can't wrap them in a using statement, because they don't implement IDisposable. And they don't expose any public Close or Dispose or similarly named methods.

In short, I'm trying to ask:

a) How can I force my c# application to close a given handle, knowing only the path to the file handle?

Or

b) Is there a way to force the Redemption objects to close?

```
var util = new MAPIUtilsClass();
    
MessageItem item = util.GetItemFromMsgFile(EmailPath, false);
                      
item.Import(EmailPath, 3);
    
Subject = item.Subject;
    
From = (item.SenderName.Length < 96) ? item.SenderName : item.SenderName.Substring(0, 93) + "...";
    
To = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.To)) ? String.Empty : (item.To.Length < 96) ? item.To : item.To.Substring(0, 93) + "...";
    
CC = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.CC)) ? String.Empty : (item.CC.Length < 96) ? item.CC : item.CC.Substring(0, 93) + "...";
    
Sent = item.SentOn;
    
Received = item.ReceivedTime;
    
Log.Write("Redemption: Email data harvested" + EmailPath);
```

Comment: Without the code, how do you think we can help you?!

Comment: Does the MAPIUtilsClass class implement IDisposable? If so, wrap that sucker in a using and that should take care of your problem.

Comment: @Brian - no sadly it doesn't either, nor does it expose a close method etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `MAPIUtils.GetItemFromMsgFile` - it is deprecated.
Use `RDOSession.GetMessageFromMsgFile` (or `CreateMessageFromMsgFile`) - it returns `IRDOMail` object which does support `IDisposable`.

Comment: The problem I've found with the RDOSession object is that it requires you to be connected to Exchange which I might not have credentials for..

Comment: No, GetMessageFromMsgFile does not require a live MAPI session unless you access properties that would require it, such as RDOMail.Sender. RDOMail.SenderEmailAddress etc. are fine since they are read directly off the message.

Comment: Maybe I'm using an old version, but I can't see IRDOMail implementing IDisposable ?

Answer (score 2):

Try calling `util.CleanUp` after you are done.

Comment: +1 - it now works having immediately called GC.Collect() afterwards and putting it in a finally statement of a try-catch

Answer (score 0):

Use Util.CleanUp() method as suggested by Daniel, but succeed it immediately with GC.Collect() and put it within a finally statement of a try-catch.

So the code now looks like this:

```
    MAPIUtilsClass util = null;

    try
    {

        util = new MAPIUtilsClass();

        MessageItem item = util.GetItemFromMsgFile(EmailPath, false);

        item.Import(EmailPath, 3);

        Subject = item.Subject;

        From = (item.SenderName.Length < 96) ? item.SenderName : item.SenderName.Substring(0, 93) + "...";

        To = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.To)) ? String.Empty : (item.To.Length < 96) ? item.To : item.To.Substring(0, 93) + "...";

        CC = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.CC)) ? String.Empty : (item.CC.Length < 96) ? item.CC : item.CC.Substring(0, 93) + "...";

        Sent = item.SentOn;

        Received = item.ReceivedTime;

        util.Cleanup();

        Log.Write("Redemption: Email data harvested: " + EmailPath);


    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        Log.Write(String.Format("Error using Redemption API against: {0}\r\n{1}\r\n{2}",
            this.EmailPath, exp.Message, exp.StackTrace));
    }

    finally
    {
        if (util != null)
            util.Cleanup();

        GC.Collect();
    }
```